# Crontab or cron.d to run a wav file. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, cron

I have been at this for a month now.  New to programming.  Trying to run a schedule for wav files to execute.  Using Raspberry Pi 3 and Raspbian Stretch.  My cron.d file called 'BellCron' is as follows:

```
/5 * * * * pi /home/pi/CronJobs/BellsCron.sh
```

Applied chmod +x to the BellsCron.sh file.

It is a file that executes a second file, 'playAngelus.py'.  When I execute 'BellsCron.sh' at the command line it works fine.

The 'BellsCron.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

sudo -u pi python /home/pi/CronJobs/playAngelus.py
```

The 'playAngelus.py' file looks like this:

```
#!/user/bin/env python

import pygame

import time

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/pi/Music/Angelus.wav")

pygame.mixer.music.play()

time.sleep(10)
```

I have also run a text file from the same cron.d file that is giving me the time in a file every 2 minutes, so I know it is running cron.  But, the sound file will not work using cron.  I accept that the error is mine.  I have tried every configuration I can find on the web.  I would be most appreciative if someone would help me to write the script I need to execute a wav file in my home directory, /home/pi/Music/Angelus.wav, using cron.d or crontab.

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to `sudo -u pi …`, as that's just reverting your cron job back to the default Raspbian user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

sudo -u pi python /home/pi/CronJobs/playAngelus.py

I think 'python' should be replaced with full path of python executable, something like: /usr/bin/python

So your code should look something like:
sudo -u pi /usr/bin/python /home/pi/CronJobs/playAngelus.py

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I was sooo close.  After what seemed like 50 combinations of entries, you showed me the 51st, and the right one at that .  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply play the wav file directly from the cron job ?

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/aplay /home/pi/Music/Angelus.wav
```

Comment: Tried this, but without success, even after reboot.  But the solution was found.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This works on my Pi3

Comment: I'd be interested to see what your log states : 'grep CRON /var/log/syslog'

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a graphical login, audio depends on X display access. cron jobs don't have the right environment variables set. I had a setup that produced an hourly chime, and this is what worked.

Install *play*, the sox audio player:

```
sudo apt install sox libsox-fmt-all
```

Edit your crontab the recommended way:

```
crontab -e
```

Add this line, save and exit:

```
*/5 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/play -q /home/pi/Music/Angelus.wav
```

Comment: Tried this, but to no avail.  However, the solution was found.   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define XDG. For example:

```
* * * * * XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u) /path/to/script
```

Sound started working for me. Do not forget to edit job timing so it does not run every minute.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497130/audio-doesnt-play-with-crontab-on-raspberry-pi)